# in htaccess redirect url following a rule

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, redirect

`enter code here`i have developed a facebook application for example on apps.facebook.com/myappname/, it's a web application hosts on myappname.mydomain.com.

in facebook applications just the url base is different, the second part url is the same, for example:

myappname.mydomain.com/home
apps.facebook.com/myappname/home

myappname.mydomain.com/product
apps.facebook.com/myappname/product

i'd like show just facebook url, not real url so for this reason i need to create a rule redirect in htaccess. i mean a rule which changes just base url from apps.facebook.com/myappname/ to myappname.mydomain.com/

is it possibile? tx, best regards

waiting help i'm working on solution and maybe this is apart of one. in htaccess i added this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !apps.facebook.com/myappname$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://apps.facebook.com/myappname/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but as you know facebook application is like an iframe so in this way starts a included loop an my app doesn't work. i need add condition to this rule, "when url is not in facebook iframe" have idea? tx

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Give it a try and let us know how it goes.

Comment: is this a reply? what means?

Comment: Let me see if I understand: You want to map all requests like `myappname.mydomain.com/whatever` to `apps.facebook.com/myappname/whatever` or is it the opposite? In any case you must have access to the .htaccess file in the root of the requested URL,¿do you?

Comment: yes, with htaccess rule i need to redirect myappname.mydomain.com/whatever to apps.facebook.com/myappname/whatever. yes i can modify htaccess. tx

Answer (score 0):

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !apps.facebook.com/myappname$ [NC]

This will always be true, because a request reaching *your* server will never have the HTTP_HOST set to apps.facebook.com. (And the path component of an URL is not part of the domain name …)

The only thing you could do with mod_rewrite in this case is checking the HTTP Referer, I guess – if it’s anything else than apps.facebook.com, then your app is likely being called outside of the FB iframe. (But how unreliable the referer is, should be common knowledge by now.)

---

Your best bet is to use JavaScript to check if your app is being called within an iframe or on it’s own (and if it is in an iframe, assume it is on apps.facebook.com.)

```
if(top == window) {
  // not in iframe, redirect:
  window.location.href = "{your app’s URL on facebook}";
}
```

This would fire only if your app is called directly in the top browser window – if it is framed, no matter if on facebook.com or not, this code will do nothing.

You could add an `X-Frame-Options` header in your server config, so that your app will only be allowed to be displayed in an (i)frame on apps.facebook.com, and not anywhere else. If you combine that with the JS approach, you can be pretty sure that if your app is “framed”, it is on apps.facebook.com and not somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

after two working days i understand this, tx for your reply, this is my javascript solution

```
 <script>
if (parent.location.href == self.location.href) {
    window.location.href = 'https://apps.facebook.com/myappname' + window.location.pathname;
    //alert(window.location.pathname);
}
</script>
```

PS. tx to MAX!!!